# How to plot two Y values for the same x with ggplot for a scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am new to coding and R and wanted to try and use R for some data visualization. I am using ggplot and attempted to make a plot that has my species on the x axis, and on the y is the effect size calculations. I was successful in doing this. I have an effect size for size and one for muscle content of a mix of the species. I wanted to see if I could overlay the plot for size and the plot for muscle.

[Image of Size plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nidrg.png)

[Image of Muscle plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCTPH.png)

Here is my code:[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kjyt.png)

```
Species <- SZ_M_spp_data$Species
y_m <- SZ_M_spp_data$`Mean(m)`
y_sz <- SZ_M_spp_data$`Mean(sz)`
y_both <- c(y_m,y_sz)
y_both

# ggplot2 plot 
plot1 <- ggplot(SZ_M_spp_data, aes(Species, y_m)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +                                        
  geom_point(shape=19, size=3, aes(color = Species)) + #color
  theme_classic () +                  # theme (white background)
  xlab("Species") +               #xlabels and
  ylab("Mean Effect Size") +        #y labels
  ylim(-0.75,2.2) +
  ggtitle("Maternal Size vs Egg Toxicant Load") +  #title
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))

plot2 <- ggplot(SZ_M_spp_data, aes(Species, y_sz)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +                                        
  geom_point(shape=15, size=3, aes(color = Species)) + #color
  theme_classic () +                  # theme (white background)
  xlab("Species") +               #xlabels and
  ylab("Mean Effect Size") +     #y labels
  ylim(-0.75,2.2) +
  ggtitle("Maternal Size vs Egg Toxicant Load") +  #title
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

I just wish to have the muscle and size points for the species on the same plot with different aes (sqaure for muscle and circles for size).. I just do not know how to have two different y values for the same x. Here is the [raw data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbTn5.png)

I look forward to your response, thanks!

Comment: Hi Brandon. It's difficult to help you here without reproducible data. The "raw data table" you posted is a _picture_ of your data, not reproducible data that we can copy and paste to replicate your plot. Could you perhaps edit your question to include the output of `dput(SZ_M_spp_data)` so that we can produce a working solution for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two geom_points. Specifying the same X axis in `ggplot()` function and the Y axis for each in the `geom_point()` function

Something like this

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Specie)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = variable1))+
  geom_point(aes(y = variable2))
```